# Apply texture to the full height of the UV Island?

Tags: texturing, uv

Full faces are unwrapped but it shows the texture like not the full height, please help!

[image]

.blend file
[image]

Comment: It may be that you are still using the Generated coordinates, even though you have already unwrapped your object. Consider uploading your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that others can inspect what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a look at your file. The texture appears that way because of the subsurf modifer. You have to tell blender there's a crease there by selecting the edges around the label and setting the crease to 1. See image:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: No problem! Also I'm a lady :)